# Why simple interface can't assign to Record<string, any>?

Tags: typescript, type-safety

Trying to create generic type for CSV file.

```
export interface Row {
    id: number;
    name: string;
}

export type CsvFile<T = Record<string, any>> = {
    data: T[];
    headers: Array<keyof T>;
};

function some(f: CsvFile) {
...
}
let test: CsvFile<Row>;
some(test);

 error TS2345: Argument of type 'CsvFile<Row>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'CsvFile<Record<string, any>>'.
  Type 'Record<string, any>' is missing the following properties from type 'Row': id, name
```

In some answers I read that I can use type inplace of interface but this not helps, error stay the same. Even with index signature:

```
export type Row = {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  [index: string]: any;
}
```

Nothing changes :(

Comment: look at https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7#code/C4TwDgpgBASg9gdygXigbwLACgpQJYAmAXFAHYCuAtgEYQBOA3NrqQIaUQkDOwdepAcyY4oAbX4EIAD269+AgLokKNelAA+UHn0HCAvtmyhIsRACYU6ZvgJnlVWo2tsOdrXN3XxpSTPc7Fe1U6DX95fUMsY2gAYS4ANwAxPAAbCAAeABUoaWAIHy5YCABjODoCdIBrCBA4ADMoTIAaMgc1TW15AD4uy0wRXAJWYFYSTNEFYVxcAAsIVkk6LhIAQTo6VhAqmvrGrv1hbDryUmLgPDhSLTgOLJypPIKi0vLt2obm1uDQzsEegAo6iQ4klUhlMl0AJRWLAAelh2AMWDSwCgeR4wISyTS6XgCH22C4Nwg-3RwEhh2REFRZLcIOxGTxZgJWCJHFJEB4ZgpQA

Comment: it should be T extends Record<string, any> not T=Records

Comment: This is a design limitation in TypeScript; see [microsoft/TypeScript#43608](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43608).  There are likely workarounds, possibly by forcing a structural comparison.  Here, [like this](https://tsplay.dev/mLRG4w).  @Crusader does that work for you?  If so I can write up an answer; if not, please elaborate on the failing use cases.

Answer (score 0):

here is a working example
juste replace `T =Record<string, any>>` with `T extends  Record<string, any>>`

```
export interface Row {
    id: number;
    name: string;
}

export type CsvFile<T extends  Record<string, any>> = {
    data: T[];
    headers: Array<keyof T>;
};

function some(f: CsvFile<Row>) {
console.log("jlkl")
}
let test: CsvFile<Row>;
some(test);
```

Comment: I think the point of the `some` function is to take any CsvFile, hence I'd suggest `function some<T>(f: CsvFile<T>) {` instead.